# Raising and listening to events from a Model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

I have a Backbone application whose model looks like this:

It is basically a Music Browser application. The Application loads multiple Albums, and each album has an AlbumMetadata object associated with it.

Also, The album has a collection of Songs, and each song has a SongMetadata object associated with it.

So basically, the object hierarchy is something like this:

```
Albums (Collection)
    |
    |____ Album 1 (Model)
         |
         |____ AlbumMetadata (Model)
         |
         |
         |____ Songs (Collection)
                    |
                    |____ Song 1 (Model)
                    |           |
                    |           |____ SongMetadata (Model)
                    |
                    |____ Song 2 (Model)
                                |
                                |____ SongMetadata (Model)
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var MusicBrowser = MusicBrowser || {};

MusicBrowser.SongMetadata = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }

});

MusicBrowser.AlbumMetadata = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var songMetadata = new MusicBrowser.SongMetadata({ albumId: this.collection.albumId, songId: this.get("Id") });
        this.set("metadata", songMetadata);
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BundleBrowser.Song,
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.albumId = options.albumId;
        this.fetch();
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var songs = new MusicBrowser.Songs([], { albumId: this.get('Id') });
        this.set('songs', songs);

        var albumMetadata = new MusicBrowser.AlbumMetadata({ albumId: this.get('Id') });
        this.set("metadata", albumMetadata);
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MusicBrowser.Album,
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```

I want to be able to automatically update the SongMetadata of each song in the Songs collection, when the AlbumMetadata of the parent Album Model is updated. How do I do this via events?

How do I raise events from the AlbumMetadata object and subscribe to that event from the SongMetadata Model in the Songs Collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as :

```
var MusicBrowser = MusicBrowser || {};

MusicBrowser.SongMetadata = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }

});

MusicBrowser.AlbumMetadata = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var songMetadata = new MusicBrowser.SongMetadata({ albumId: this.collection.albumId, songId: this.get("Id") });
        this.set("metadata", songMetadata);

        this.bind('albumMetadata', function(albumMetadata) {
            // here you have the albumMetadata and the songMetadata
        });
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BundleBrowser.Song,
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.albumId = options.albumId;
        this.fetch();

        this.bind('albumMetadata', function(albumMetadata) { 
            _.each(this.models, function(model) {
                model.trigger('albumMetadata', albumMetadata); 
            });
        });
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var songs = new MusicBrowser.Songs([], { albumId: this.get('Id') });
        this.set('songs', songs);

        var albumMetadata = new MusicBrowser.AlbumMetadata({ albumId: this.get('Id') });
        this.set("metadata", albumMetadata);
        albumMetadata.bind('change', function() { songs.trigger('albumMetadata', this); }, albumMetadata);
    }
});

MusicBrowser.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MusicBrowser.Album,
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```